# CSS: scrollable flex container is not displaying scrollbars unless it has height set with calc() or absolute values

Tags: css, flexbox

#### Problem

I have a scrollable flex container. The problem is the vertical scrollbar is not showing up unless I define the element's height with `calc()` or absolute values like `px`.

What are the usual causes for this?

#### Solutions I tried

I tried specifying `height: 100%` and `display: flex` for all parent containers but it didn't help.

#### Code

**[Link](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/a383a2fba427fb30b8bfce464e352e8d8201b4f0/src/components/VirtualList/index.vue#L564)** to file on Github

I'm solving this now by calculating `100vh - UI components above it`

```
.virtual-list__root-container {
  overflow: overlay;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(
    100vh -
    var(--window-toolbar-height) -
    var(--action-toolbar-height) -
    var(--workspace-area-toolbar-height) - 
    var(--workspace-area-sorting-header-height)
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask, why doesn't your `.virtual-list__root-container` has a `overflow-y: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll` if you want to have a scrollbar?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It has a custom class with `overflow: overlay`. The weird thing is the scrollbar is shown only when I use absolute values like `height: 500px` or the `calc()` function. I'm not sure why can't CSS calculate the height when I set `height: 100%`. Do you by any chance know what can cause this behavior?

Comment: I just cloned your project, I will dig a bit if I find a solution I will come back to this.

Comment: Cheers mate, let me know if you have any difficulties running it locally. It should launch on Windows without any problems on `Node v15.14.0`

Comment: Sadly the `DirItem` component throws thousand of errors for me so when I run `electron:serve` i can't really test the main directory listing. Tested with Node 15.14 and 16.15. Really unfortunate.

Comment: @Laisender sorry mate, I didn't have the local changes on git, I fixed the problem with directory items

Answer (score 0):

You could try `overflow-y:scroll;` for verticall scrollbar or `overflow-x:scroll;` for horizontal scroll bar to show